# flex application bind to url

Tags: apache-flex

The problem with flex applications is that a user can download it and run it on his local machine or possibly host it on another site. Is it possible to lock a flex application to a domain name to prevent such acts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you'll do something like this in your application initialization area :

```
var domainList : String = 'mysite.com,anothersite.com';
var domainCheck : String = this.url.split('/')[2];
var foundValidDomain : Boolean = false;
for each ( var domainChecking : String in domainList.split(',')){
    if( domainCheck.toUpperCase().indexOf(domainChecking.toUpperCase()) >= 0 ){
        mx.controls.Alert.show( 'check success: "' + domainCheck + '" against: "' + domainChecking ); 
        foundValidDomain = true;
        break;
    }else{                          
        mx.controls.Alert.show( 'check failed: "' + domainCheck + '" against: "' + domainChecking );
    }
}
if( !foundValidDomain ){
    // oh noes! mad hax!
    this.visible = false; // or however you want to lock it down
    return;
}
```

Make sense?   :)

Now, if you want to lock it down more, you can have your app post to a server with a key string and have the server send some encrypted time-sensitive instructions back (send date/time to server and back, etc).  This would add another layer of hassle having to implement the server side as well.  This is probably overkill for most applications.

Comment: Thanks for acceptance.  Obviously you'll remove the Alerts when you deploy, that's just for testing / instructional.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write the code yourself, but you could access the [URL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#url) variable of the application tag and disable the app if the domain is not your domain.

I wouldn't call this an unbeatable measure, but I don't think anything is.

I'm not sure why this 'problem' is unique to Flex applications.

Comment: why is there a method of going around this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @user44444444 one way to go around this is to make the flex application think that is running on the original website. This can be done easy by having a web server locally and using the hosts file or a dns server to give the wrong ip (originaldomain.com -> 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link http://www.richardlord.net/blog/protecting-a-swf

Basically, you can solve the problem by locking down the domain as you say, and also you can potentially encrypt your code using commercial solutions - which are discussed in the link. I think the main point is if you publish Flex code externally you want people to run it.